# como hacer para que cuando me logueo en laravel me retorne los datos del usuario y se almacene en una session o un localstorage

Tags: php, html5, laravel

Hola soy nuevo en laravel, uso laravel 5.6  estoy implementando un login con `function __construct(){$this->middleware('auth.basic');}` es una autentificacion básica , este constructor  lo inserto en canda controller. lo que necesito es que cada que se  inicia sesion  me devuelva los datos del usuario  y se almacenen en una session o en el  localstorage(no se donde deba alamcenarlo). para que  cuando este usuario  registre algo este registro lleve con sigo el id del usuario  y asi porder saber quien guardo ese registro. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si estás usando la autenticación de Laravel podés acceder a los datos del usuario autenticado haciendo:

Usando la Facade Auth

```
    \Auth::user()
```

Usando el helper

```
    auth()->user()
```

Documentación: [Retrieving The Authenticated User](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user)

---

Además no es necesario que agregues el middleware a todos los controladores. Podés crear un grupo de rutas que implemente el middleware y listo.

```
// Todas las rutas definidas en este grupo van a tener el middleware auth
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeControler@index');

});
```

Documentación: [Route Groups](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-groups)